# Forcing Windows to mount a drive with a specific drive letter

Tags: windows-7, usb, mount, truecrypt, bitlocker

I have a USB key with sensitive data on it. It contains a TrueCrypt container, which I can mount to a specific drive letter through a TrueCrypt installation on the same device.

This is all great, except for the fact that TrueCrypt regularly causes BSODs and my support requests regarding these issues have gone unanswered.

So I'm looking into BitLocker encryption. Which seems great, except for the fact that I have no control over the drive letter under which the drive will be mounted. Obviously I could change the drive letter through the Computer Management console after mounting the device. But that is a PITA if you have to do it several times a day.

It's important for the mounted device to have a specific drive letter because several applications look for SSL certificates and encryption keys at that specific location.

In my mind, I'm hoping for a solution similar to how the Linux `mount` works.

Comment: Not really an answer, but... http://www.freeotfe.org/

Comment: @Ignacio Thanks, I'll look into that as an alternative solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you change the drive letter once, Windows should remember that.

You should also try to find out what causes the BSODs. I doubt that it's TrueCrypt alone since it runs on thousands of PCs without crashing them.

So maybe make a screenshot and post that here. We might be able to point you in the right direction.

On top of that, [this blog post might help](http://kladde.org/~meid/blog/index.php/bluescreen-with-truecrypt-on-mounting-container/), too. Or Google for "truecrypt bsod".

Comment: I had several occasions where the "wrong" drive letter was used. I didn't find the behavior to be reliable enough.  
I have researched the BSOD problems with TrueCrypt for quite some time and actually read that blog post already. The BSODs only happen when mounting multiple drives. Also they only happen in like 30-40% of my mounting procedures. I might not have the most common use case. Maybe I'll open another question for this ;)

Comment: In the past I often had problems with USB keys that were assigned a low letter (like F or G). These could be taken up by other keys under certain circumstances. After I changed my key's letter to X, I can now avoid those conflicts. So you were in fact correct.

Comment: This isnt an answer, more a clarification so people don't get the wrong idea that TrueCrypt is safe or stable. Their BSOD issue is so prevalent that they have a special 'new forum post' intercept page addressing it, with an attempt at an automated debugger, which fails, too. I also tried changing the letters to decending from Z, since that's how the TrueCrypt volume creation wizard does it- but apparently there's no logic to, or functional reason for that. Thanks for pointing out that it's a multiple drive issue.